# Flutter, my inputs getting cleared when re-openning page with bottomnavbar

Tags: flutter

I have a bottomnavigation bar and 3 pages. I move between these 3 pages with Get.to() in bottomnavigationbar. I have some input fields in one of those pages. I write inputs then I go to another page with bottomnavigationbar and then I reopen that page again but every input I wrote is cleared. I want to save the state of that page or with other words, I don't want these inputs to get cleared when moving to another page. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `Get.to()`, meaning you using `get` libbrary.

In this case you need to put your `TextEditingController` to your `GetxController` and binding in the page that contains your bottomnavigationbar. Now the parent page was hold the `GetxController` who will store your textfield state instead of widget state.

Or just adding `permanent: true` to your controller binding.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it with IndexedStack.